# Why is my connect not firing off the signal function?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to learn Qt and wanted to start off with a small project.

I added a pushbutton to my project with the name "playPauseButton". Currently, I am trying to connect it to a signal in a class which should handle all the button events, determining the current event with an enum value given in my SLOT.

This is my code right now:

```
connect(ui.playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_uiInit.get(), SLOT(ClickEvents(Buttons::PausePlayButton)));
```

Note that `m_uiInit` is a `shared_ptr` pointing to the class which has the `ClickEvents()` method in it:

```
std::shared_ptr<UIInit> m_uiInit = std::shared_ptr<UIInit>(new UIInit());
```

My slot in the UIInit class looks like this:

Header:

```
public slots:

    void ClickEvents(Buttons button);
```

Cpp:

```
void UIInit::ClickEvents(Buttons button)
{
    switch (button)
    {
    case Buttons::PausePlayButton:
        //Do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working?

I suspect it's due to the third argument in the connect()-call. I often saw it with just "this", but I read up on it and found that it seems like it has to be a pointer to the object of the class containing the SLOT method?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistency between the signal and the slot signatures - the signal has no parameter, the slot requires one parameter. Signatures must match, it is OK if the signal has say an int and a float parameters, in this case you can connect to a slot that takes only an int parameter, and the float will be discarded. In your case you connect a `signal(void)` to a `slot(enum)`, but where does the enum value come from?

Instead create another slot that takes no parameters and connect the signal to it, and in that slot `m_uiInit.get()->ClickEvents(Buttons::PausePlayButton);`

In Qt the signal parameter is not specified upon connection, but upon signal emission - `emit someSignal(param)`.

That being said, you can use the new connection syntax available in Qt5, and connect to a lambda, which will capture the needed data. It will be similar to creating the auxiliary slot, but it will be an unnamed function for each button instead (only works in Qt5+):

```
connect(ui->playPauseButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){ m_uiInit.get()->ClickEvents(Buttons::PausePlayButton); });
```

BTW, `ui` is a pointer, so `ui.playPauseButton` is wrong as well.

Comment: Is there a way to use one general slot function then, but still be able to determine which button called the function? I would have to give some kind of information, right?

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Finally some C++ home soil with the sight of lambdas :) Regarding ui, It was autogenerated to be a object in my case. I was actually thinking this was standard behaviour

Answer (score 0):

1) If the connect fails, you should get a run-time warning

2) Look at [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) for the "a class which should handle all the button events" stuff